# pointers and struct c

Tags: c, pointers, struct

this is my structs

```
typedef struct lists
{
struct reasonslist* alist;
}lists;

struct reasonslist
{
    char* proreasons;
    int numr;
    char* conreasons;
    int numc;
};
```

main

```
int main(void)
{
    char str[100] = "";
    lists dielema = {0};
    printf("write your reason: ");
    getchar();
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);
    dielema.alist->proreasons=  &str;
```

it's not work how i can compare  str into my struct i try 
*(dielema.alist->proreasons) = str
 its not  worked too

Comment: Looks like you forgot to post the rest of your [mcve] and to explain more about how it is not working.

Comment: Don't you mean "copy", not "compare"? Anyway, you cannot copy as there is nowhere to copy to; you need to look at `malloc()` and friends, or more simply do `char proreasons[100];`.

Comment: how i do it with malloc() i need this be Dynamic

Comment: You forgot to allocated the memory. Allocate memory in runtime using malloc() because you don’t know the size of str. Malloc() allocates the memory in heap and you need to free() the memory once your done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work, because you don't allocate memory for `alist`. Also after you fix that, you should allocate memory for the `proreasons`. Otherwise when ever you re-use the `str` to read more lines from *stdin*, your `proreasons` will change.

```
char str[100] = { 0 };
dielema.alist = malloc(sizeof(reasonslist));
dielema.alist->proreasons = malloc(strnlen(str, 100) + 1);
```

Comment: tnx you very helpful

Comment: The last line _only_ allocates the memory for the string -- you must also copy the string to the allocated space. There is a nonstandard `allocate and copy` in single command `dielema.alist->proreasons = strdup(str);` with the security problem of `str` not necessarily having a terminating ascii zero.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems, here are two of the worst:

1. `dielema.alist` is a pointer, but you never make it point anywhere. Are you sure it *needs* to be a pointer? Since it's not initialized its value will be *indeterminate* and dereferencing it will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
2. `str` is an array, `&str` is a pointer to the array. The type of `&str` is `char (*)[100]`, which is semantically very different from `char *`. Remember that arrays naturally decays to pointer to their first element, i.e. `str` is the same as `&str[0]`, and its type is `char *`.

I'm guessing the compiler is complaining about the second issue?

Lastly note that by making `dielema.alist->proreasons` point to the first character of `str` (once you fixed the first problem above) then you are lucky that you do this in the `main` function. That means the life-time of the `str` array will be the life-time of the `main` function which is usually the full run-time of the program. If you had done this in another function then `str` would go out of scope when the function returned, and any pointers to it would become invalid.